# Roslaunch required=true only kills nodes in the same machine

Tags: ros, roslaunch, multi-machine

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am executing a multi-node ROS (ROS Fuerte Ubuntu 12.04) architecture. These nodes are spread in different machines. When a certain node finishes, I want the rest to be killed. I thought that using required=true parameter in the roslaunch would be sufficient. However, I found that, when the node finishes, only the nodes located in the same machine would be killed as well. Is there any way to make all the nodes in all the machines be killed (I mean automatically, not using Ctrl-C in the roslaunch).

Thank you in advance,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56302/roslaunch-required=true-only-kills-nodes-in-the-same-machine/) by [Javier J. Salmerón García](https://answers.ros.org/users/4037/javier-j.-salmer%C3%B3n-garc%C3%ADa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2013-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the source of the problem. The required was not in the same machine as the roslaunch was being run. I changed the node to the same machine where the roslaunch was being done and it worked perfectly.

---

Originally posted by [Javier J. Salmerón García](https://answers.ros.org/users/4037/javier-j.-salmer%C3%B3n-garc%C3%ADa/) with karma: 114 on 2013-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2